# C++ unable to create template constructor with template parameter

Tags: c++, class, templates, undefined-reference

```
    person<worker> people (w);
```

I have `person` class and `worker` class, I want to create people objects from the `person` class.

```
//person.cpp
template <class T>
person<T>::~person()
{
    //dtor
}

//person.h
template <class T>
class person
{
    public:
        person();
        person(T a);
        virtual ~person();

};
```

I get

```
undefined reference to `person<worker>::person(worker).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you defined this: `person(T a);`?

Comment: Like all undefined reference error, there is a function you didn't defined or you don't compile the file that contained it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor taking a `worker` is not defined. You only have the header, not the definition. This leads to the error

[image]

I added the definition in the class declaration as this:

```cpp
person(T a) { x = a; };
```

Here is a minimal code that compiles and executes (from what you have done) :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class worker
{
 private:
    int a;
  public:
    worker(){}
    ~worker() {}
};

//person.h
template <class T>
class person
{
    public:
        person();
        person(T a) { x = a; };
        virtual ~person();

    private:
        T x;

};

//person.cpp
template <class T>
person<T>::~person()
{
    //dtor
}

int main()
{
    worker w;
    person<worker> people(w);

}
```